Correspondence between sheaves of ideals and closed immersion
Let $(X,\mathcal O_X)$ be a locally ringed space.
Let $\mathcal J$ be a sheaf of ideals over $\mathcal O_X$. Then we can construct a closed immersion of locally ringed spaces: $$(Z(\mathcal J),i^{-1}(\mathcal O_X/\mathcal J))\xrightarrow{(i,i^\#)} (X,\mathcal O_X),$$ where $Z(\mathcal J)\subset X$ is the set of $x\in X$ such that $\mathcal J_x\subsetneq \mathcal O_{X,x}$, which is closed, and $i:Z\hookrightarrow X$ is the inclusion.
If we take $\operatorname{ker}i^\#$, do we get back $\mathcal J$? I think no because for example, if $X$ is an affine scheme, the kernel of any closed immersion into $X$ is quasi-coherent, so if we choose $\mathcal J$ not quasi-coherent, we surely do not get it back.
Hence I wanted to ask: is $\operatorname{ker}i^\#$ in general obtained by $\mathcal J$ via some canonical construction?
Edit after answer. Let $(X,\mathcal O_X)$ be a locally ringed space, and let $\mathcal J$ be a sheaf of ideals over $\mathcal O_X$. There is a canonical morphism of ring sheaves $i^\#:\mathcal O_X\to i_*i^{-1}(\mathcal O_X/\mathcal J)$, where $i:Z(\mathcal J)\hookrightarrow X$ is the inclusion defined above.
We want to prove that $\operatorname {ker}i^\#=\mathcal J$ by proving that they are equal on the stalks, so let's compute $(\operatorname {ker}i^\#)_x=\operatorname {ker}(i^\#_x)$ at any $x\in X$.
Suppose first that $x\in Z(\mathcal J)$. Look at the canonical map: $$\mathcal O_{X,x}\to i_*i^{-1}(\mathcal O_X/\mathcal J)_x\to i^{-1}(\mathcal O_X/\mathcal J)_x$$ the first map $i^\#_x$ factors as: $$\mathcal O_{X,x}\to(\mathcal O_X/\mathcal J)_x\to i_*i^{-1}(\mathcal O_X/\mathcal J)_x$$ and we know that the composition: $$(\mathcal O_X/\mathcal J)_x\to i_*i^{-1}(\mathcal O_X/\mathcal J)_x\to i^{-1}(\mathcal O_X/\mathcal J)_x$$ is just the canonical isomorphism. Moreover since $i$ is an immersion we have that $i_*i^{-1}(\mathcal O_X/\mathcal J)_x\to i^{-1}(\mathcal O_X/\mathcal J)_x$ is an isomorphism, proving that $\operatorname {ker}(i^\#_x)=\mathcal J_x$.
If instead $x\in X\setminus Z(\mathcal J)$, we know that $\mathcal J_x=\mathcal O_{X,x}$, and $i_*i^{-1}(\mathcal O_X/\mathcal J)_x=0$, so automatically $\operatorname{ker}(i^\#_x)=\mathcal O_{X,x}$.
Thus since $\operatorname{ker}(i^\#_x)$ and $\mathcal J_x$ coincide as ideals of =$\mathcal O_{X,x}$ for all $x\in X$, we conclude that they coincide as sheaves of ideals.

If you choose $\mathcal{J}$ to not be quasi-coherent, then $(Z(\mathcal{J}), i^{-1}(\mathcal{O}_X/\mathcal{J}))$ will not be a scheme, so the kernel of $i^#$ does not need to be quasi-coherent. I believe that the kernel of $i^#$ will be $\mathcal{J}$ but I admit I have not thought about closed immersions in the non-scheme case much.

Thanks, I finally understood what is bothering me: I was convinced that any closed immersion of LRS into $\operatorname{Spec} A$ is of the form $\operatorname {Spec}A/I$, instead this is true only for closed immersions of schemes

It is true we get $\ker i^\#=\mathcal{J}$, and really is not a thing about schemes. Up to isomorphism underneath the mother space, closed immersions of locally ringed spaces are exactly determined by the ideal sheaves $\mathcal{J}$. The other part of that correspondence is linked at the bottom of this answer.
What is $i^\#$? Well, it is the composition $\mathscr{O}_X\to\mathscr{O}_X/\mathcal{J}\to i_\ast i^\ast(\mathscr{O}_X/\mathcal{J})$ (adjunct to $i^\ast\mathscr{O}_X\overset{i^\ast(\text{quotient})}{\longrightarrow}i^\ast(\mathscr{O}_X/\mathcal{J}))$.
The kernel of the first leg is $\mathcal{J}$, so surely we should hope for the last map to be injective (as  a map of sheaves) and then the composition will also have kernel sheaf $\mathcal{J}$ as desired. Alright, so why should the last map - the unit map for $i^\ast\dashv i_\ast$ - be injective?
Let $\mathscr{F}:=\mathscr{O}_X/\mathcal{J}$ for brevity, a locally ringed sheaf. We can always compute the kernel of this unit map "explicitly" - we can write down a short exact sequence: $$0\to j_!j^\ast\mathscr{F}\to\mathscr{F}\to i_\ast i^\ast\mathscr{F}\to0$$Where $j:X\setminus Z(\mathcal{J})\hookrightarrow X$ is the open immersion complementary to $i$. If you're not familiar with the adjunctions at play there or with the necessary exactness properties, feel free to double-check with me; the fact $i$ is closed is quite important for this to work. Why do we care about this sequence? Because the final map is the one we care for - we want to show it is injective, so we want to show its kernel, necessarily $j_!j^\ast\mathscr{F}$, is the zero sheaf.
Ok, compute its stalks! At $x\in Z(\mathcal{J})$, the stalks are zero (... which is more or less the reason why the sequence is exact in the first place). The only possible trouble is at points $x\in X\setminus Z(\mathcal{J})$, where $\mathscr{F}$ may pick up some fringe, nonzero boundary values. Compute $(j_!j^\ast\mathscr{F})_x\cong\mathscr{F}_x$... and $\mathscr{F}_x\cong\mathscr{O}_{X,x}/\mathcal{J}_x=\mathscr{O}_{X,x}/\mathscr{O}_{X,x}=0$ precisely because $X\setminus Z(\mathcal{J})$ is the set of all points where $\mathcal{J}$ has full stalk. Hence, $\mathscr{F}\to i_\ast i^\ast\mathscr{F}$ is injective and $i^\#$'s kernel is just the kernel of $\mathscr{O}_X\to\mathscr{O}_X/\mathcal{J}$ i.e. just $\mathcal{J}$.
See the bottom of this answer for similar stuff about closed immersions of locally ringed spaces.
EDIT, following comments: here in this proof, I make sure to emphasise that we get $\ker i^\#=\mathcal{J}$ by looking at a map into $\mathscr{O}_X$; kernels are maps, not just objects. Moreover, simply checking the stalks are abstractly isomorphic isn't good enough in general - we also need to see the stalks are made isomorphic via the maps we consider. For a simple counterexample, consider $Y$ to be the Sierpinski space with open point $0$, underlying set $\{0,1\}$, and let $X=\{0\}$. Let $f:X\hookrightarrow Y$ be the inclusion; let $\mathscr{F}$ be the sheaf on $Y$ with: $\mathscr{F}(Y)=R,\mathscr{F}(\{0\})=R,\mathscr{F}(\emptyset)=0$ and the only nontrivial restriction being any nonidentity map $R\to R$, e.g. the zero map. Here $R$ is any ring, or Abelian group, or $k$-module... depending exactly on what sort of sheaves you want to think about. The canonical unit map $\mathscr{F}\to f_\ast f^{-1}\mathscr{F}$ is not an isomorphism, yet if you take stalks at the two points of $Y$ you see the the stalks are abstractly isomorphic (it's just that the unit map doesn't induce this isomorphism). Note $f$ is an open embedding; if it were a closed embedding then actually no counterexamples of this sort exist. But the point stands that in general, abstractly checking the stalks are isomorphic is no good.

Thank you, but I'm not very practical so your answer is quite obscure to me. If you have some time, you may look at the edit I made: I tried to prove the same thing with my tools, I'd be glad to know if my arguments work or they are wrong. Thanks again!

@EzioGreggio Your arguments look to be more or less the same as mine and are correct. In the first part you are implicitly saying that we have $\mathscr{O}_{X,x}\to(\mathscr{O}_X/\mathcal{J})x$ followed by something which is an isomorphism, so the kernel just comes from the first map and is $\mathcal{J}x$. I could have written mine more elementarily but I want to make the point that we can always figure out the kernel of $\mathscr{F}\to i\ast i^\ast\mathscr{F}$ (for closed immersions) as $j!j^\ast\mathscr{F}$, just so you can see a general method.

Note it is not correct to calculate a kernel by saying the stalks are always the stalks of some other sheaf.. what is important is that the map $\mathcal{J}\to\mathscr{O}_X$ is a kernel map for $i^#$. Two sheaves with isomorphic stalks need not be isomorphic; we must actually find a sheaf map which induces these stalkwise isomorphisms

I agree with your first comment, but I'm not sure to understand the second one. I see that two sheaves in general are isomorphic only if there is a morphism inducing the isomorphisms on every stalk, but in the case that we have two subsheaves of a sheaf $O_X$, aren't they equal if their stalk is the same subset of $O_{X,x}$ at every $x\in X$?

@EzioGreggio Yeah here's it fine, I'm just raising the small point that it's not generally enough to calculate stalks, and really our stalk calculation naturally leads to a proof that $\mathcal{J}\to\mathscr{O}_X$ is a kernel map as desired

I've been following this discussion for a while, the last your comments on that two sheaves are only isomorphic not only if their stalks are abstractly isomorphic but also there is a map between them inducing this iso brought me to an interesting point that I've been pondering about for a while:
Say $f:X \to Y $ is a map of schemes, $\mathcal{F}$ a sheaf on $Y$ with the property that at each $y$ the stalks $(f_*f^{-1}\mathcal{F})_y$ and $\mathcal{F}_y$ are abstractly isomorphic, ie we evaluate them separately and manage somehow to deduce that these are the same $y$-wise. Can we deduce

from this that the canonical unit map $\mathcal{F} \to f_*f^{-1}\mathcal{F}$ an iso?
Note the subtlety is that as assumption I only want the stalks to be abstractly isomorphic, and a priori I say nothing about if this iso comes from the unit map, so in general situation as you exposed in last comments this not suffice to show that the sheaves aere isomorphic. But my question (...or hope) is if in this specific rather "canonical" case with unit map we can(?) nevertheless already conclude the unit map should be already be an iso knowing only that the stalks are only abstractly isomorphic?

Do you have an idea on this point? So the "big question" is if the unit is "such canonical" that it gives already an iso if we know that the sheaves between it maps have only abstractly isomorphic stalks, what in general to establish an iso of sheaves not suffice, but possibly the unit map may be "such canonical" or "natural" that in this specific case it works.

@user267839 If $f:X\subset Y$ is a closed embedding then we're good; $\mathscr{F}x\cong(f\ast f^{-1}\mathscr{F})x\forall x$ iff. $\mathscr{F}\to f\ast f^{-1}\mathscr{F}$ is an isomorphism; for totally general maps $f$, this is false. Consider $Y={0,1}$ the Sierpinski space, where ${0}$ is the only nontrivial open set. Let $\mathscr{F}$ be the sheaf (of Abelian groups) with $\mathscr{F}(X)=\Bbb Z,\mathscr{F}({0})=\Bbb Z$ and restriction map any nonidentity map $\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z$ e.g. the zero map. Let $X={0}$, $f:X\hookrightarrow Y$ the inclusion. Check this is a counterexample

(So, this shows that not even other nice embeddings like open embeddings work!)

I see, thanks! On case $f$ closed immersion I guess the trick is that we can fit the unit map similarly as in your answer above in a naturally given exact sequence and then analyze the stalks of kernel sheaf "by hand", right? Or does it follow even easier? (assuming, that somebody "not knows" about the existence of such sequence)

@user267839 Well, note that for all $x\in X$, the unit map would make an isomorphism (here we used the closed embedding hypothesis). The only possible issue could be for $x\in Y\setminus X$, but note $(f_\ast f^{-1}\mathscr{F})_x=0$ for these $x$ (again using the closed hypothesis) forcing $\mathscr{F}_x=0$. Then the unit map, on these stalks, is a map $0\to 0$ which necessarily must be an isomorphism! So the unit map has to be an isomorphism on all stalks, so it is an isomorphism of the sheaves

How do you see that in case $f$ closed immersion the unit is an iso at stalks in $x \in X \subset Y$? Abstractly using the def of stalks and that $(\mathscr{F}^{-1})x=(\mathscr{F}){f(x)}$ the stalks $(f_\ast f^{-1}\mathscr{F})_x$ and $\mathscr{F}_x$ coinside, but why is this iso compatible with the unit map?

More generally, in your example with Serpinski space and canon open embedding $f:X:={0} \subset {0,1}=:Y$ the problem was - so far I understand it correctly - that even if the stalks are isomorphic, the unit is not an iso at stalk ${1} \in Y-X$, ie the problem was outside $X$; in contrast at ${0}$ it is an iso. This raises the question, if $f: X \to Y$ is arbitrary immersion and as before the stalks of $\mathscr{F}$ and $f_\ast f^{-1}\mathscr{F}$ are abstractly isomorphic. Does then the unit map induce at least an iso at points in $f(X)$?

@user267839 Arbitrary subspace inclusions $X\subset Y$ always have that the unit is an isomorphism on those points in $X$. It is just what happens outside of $X$ that can be very badly behaved (inclusions typically have inexact pushforwards e.g.)

I see that at points in $f(X)$ for $f$ immersion the stalks are isomorphic, but what is the argument that the unit induces an isomorphism? Is there a "standard argument"?

Ah, and "why is this iso compatible with the unit map?" One "method" is just to "convince yourself" by looking at explicit definitions. Maybe a more structured way is this: firstly, the canonical map $(f_\ast\mathscr{G}){f(x)}\to\mathscr{G}x$, $\mathscr{G}$ any sheaf on $X$ and $f:X\to Y$ any map, $x\in X$ any point, is an isomorphism when $f$ is an immersion (directly check it; pushforwards are easy to understand explicitly). Now let $\mathscr{G}=f^{-1}\mathscr{F}$. The map $\mathscr{F}{f(x)}\to(f\ast\mathscr{G})_{f(x)}\to\mathscr{G}_x$ is famously an isomorphism, so put these together

Thanks! Category theoretically after observing that by definition we can identify stalks $(f^{-1}\mathscr{F}){x}$ and $\mathscr{F}{f(x)}$ this argument seems to base on triangle identities ; see Prop. 2.3, Eqn 3.
